# Is it possible to access posts of a facebook page with logging in from web browser

Tags: c#, facebook

I see many posts similar to mine, but could not get a clear answer. Also I notice facebook API keep changing. I am using C# Winforms and want to access recent posts of a facebook page. I can authenticate with web browser control, but I want to do without it (I mean without logging in using UI). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed?locale=en_GB

In order to get the posts without logging in through your UI you would need to authenticate in your request yourself. Please see the following:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380635/Csharp-Application-Integration-with-Facebook-Twitt

this SDK will also help: http://facebooksdk.net/